# Ubuntu 20.04 lts Could not access fingerprint readers

Tags: drivers, 20.04, fingerprint-reader

I'm trying to set a Fingerprint login in ubuntu 20.04 but I get this message:

```
Could not access any fingerprint readers
Please contact your system administrator for help.
```

I'm thinking that some fingerprint drivers are missing, what do I do?

Comment: Not all fingerprint readers are supported.

Comment: What output do you get when you type `lsusb` in a terminal?

Comment: @Zany_Zachary1 I got this output  
`Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 27c6:5301 Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1bcf:28c1 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`

Comment: same here, HP elitebook 840 G2 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0424:5534 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 04ca:704d Lite-On Technology Corp. HP HD Webcam
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 138a:003f Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS495 Fingerprint Reader
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0424:2134 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) Hub

Comment: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=234844  Hopefully this will help.  I've found that most fingerprint drivers don't work on Linux, mine included.  Don't feel alone ;)

Comment: https://github.com/uunicorn/python-validity can help. CAUTION: USE AT YOUR OWN RISK. I only used it for testing purpose.

Answer (score 4):

Not all the fingerprint scanners have drivers in Linux.
I have the same issue with a Dell laptop. One of the easiest ways to check I've found it to use Hardware prob application. It's available in Ubuntu App store in form of a snap, you can find the description at asnapcraft webpage: [snapcraft.io](https://snapcraft.io/hw-probe)

What id does - it scanc you system and then provides you with a link to a summary. The devices that do not have drives or have some issues or pure compatibility are marked. Results are based on other user's systsems/comments (you can edit the report after it's loaded) and LKDBB: [LKDBB](https://cateee.net/lkddb/) It's open source and doesn't share you prive information (you can even find the reference in Fedora Project wiki [Fedora Wiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Hardware_probe)). If you do not want to share your specs, you still can use the search on their site: [Hardware Probe Search](https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?view=search) to find which scanner you have you can use `lsusb` and `lshw` commands.

In some cases you can try to request new drivers at libfprint gitlab page: [libfprint gitlab](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint/-/issues) but I'm not sure how effective is this as it didn't help me - the Goodix scanner I have apparently doesn't have open source code and atherefore the dirver can be provided only by manufacturer or Dell and neither of them have real interest in doing so. You can also find the list of currently supported devices there: [libfprint supported devices](https://fprint.freedesktop.org/supported-devices.html)

Hope it's not too much information at once.