# How to activate fingerprint on ubuntu 20.04 for login?

Tags: lenovo, thinkpad, fingerprint-reader

I couldn't able to enable the fingerprint by Settings->Users->Authentication & Login.

When doing like above I getting error like "Could not access any fingerprint readers Please contact your system administrator for help!"

Can anyone help to enable it.

Comment: check if you've attached a fingerprint reader and if it doesn't read, you'll need to install a driver. look here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232442/ubuntu-20-04-lts-could-not-access-fingerprint-readers?rq=1

Comment: yes, I have an inbuilt finger reader.

Comment: Run `lsusb` and identify your fingerprint reader by it's device ID. Then search https://fprint.freedesktop.org/supported-devices.html to see if it is compatible. If it isn't search the web to see if there's any other driver available.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the fingerprint-gui

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fingerprint/fingerprint-gui
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libbsapi policykit-1-fingerprint-gui fingerprint-gui
```

then launch fingerprint gui

Comment: this solution no longer work for Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: even I'm not able to use the fingerprint reader.

Comment: @sarru1289 do you know the solution??

Comment: try this command line method: https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/fingerprint-login-ubuntu-mate/20852

or ask at the official Ubuntu forum:https://discourse.ubuntu.com/ here. Someone will definitely guide you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best write up here:

https://devicetests.com/install-fingerprint-reader-lenovo-thinkpad-ubuntu

For > 2204

`sudo apt install libpam-fprintd`

You might also want to :

`sudo pam-auth-update`

For other versions - see the link.